# What is the best package to use for random forest classification when using numerical and categorical data in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest

Does anyone know about a Python package in which Random Forest handles both variable types at the same time?

I just checked and it looks like skicit-learn still relies on one-hot-encoding to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to try [H2O.ai](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html)

Yes, for tree-based models, it could be a problem if the features have lots of levels. A simple one-hot encoding might [make your trees lost in the sparsity.](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/".) I have used tree models in H2O. One nice thing about these models is that, you can directly input the raw categorical features (usually strings) without mannually [encoding them](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html). The model implementations provide an encoding option for all common encodings. The default option is Enum encoding which is quite unique because  after mapping the strings to integers, you can split {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} as {0, 4, 5} and {1, 2, 3}. The models would ignore the numerical order of the integers when splitting.

To add on that, in sklearn, we have two options for encoding categorical features: 
the native "preprocessing" module and the ["categorical encoders"](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/ordinal.html) package .   The ordinal encoder in the native module maps the strings to integers based on alphabetic order.  In the "categorical encoder" package, by default it randomly assigns integers to different categories.  This is nice, but once you throw the encoded features into sklearn models, it will be regarded as ordinal, as is explained [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-categorical-features).

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, I will definitely try H2O. The same applies to XGB, or in general GBTs?

Comment: @SimondeFauconval Be careful with the implementation of XGBoost in H2O, the default encoding is one hot encoding.